# Tkinter Generating new rows of Entry boxes not responding to Button call

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an SQLite database interface using python and Tkinter to store the results of tests. Basically, the user first selects an option from a drop-down menu (Tkinter menubar) which generates a form with 6 predefined tests for collecting input. The input from these entry boxes is then stored in SQLite, where each row/test is stored in a different table. Different materials will be tested but the tests are the same for each. I want to compare the same test results for multiple materials at a later stage to model trends etc.

So, my idea is that the menu-bar calls a function (which determines the test category, board_strength for example) to generate a form with the date and project number and which does the layout. A class is used to generate the entry boxes, get the input, calculate the average, and store the values to SQLite after each row is filled out. If the user requires an additional row for the same test, a button should add it as needed. Then, if the user moves onto the next test (maybe via a button..), they again have the option to add another row for this test, and so on. Here I've only shown 1 test, ECT, but there are 5 more.

I've tried making a button to generate a new row but it doesn't seem to work properly. I've read a few posts on this site and googled, and although I'm quite new to working with classes, it seemed the easiest way to do what I want.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

date = datetime.date.today()

class create_widgets:
    '''create widgets for input data, collect input, determine average, and store'''
    def __init__(self, window, test_name, units, row):
        self.window = root
        self.test_name = ''
        self.units = ''
        self.row = 0
        self.add_entry(window, test_name, units, row)
      
    def add_entry(self, window, test_name, units, row):
        self.entries = []

        lbl_of_test = Label(window, text = f'{test_name} ({units}):', font = ('Arial', 10))
        lbl_of_test.grid(row = row, column = 0)

        for i in range(3):
            self.entry = Entry(window, width=8)
            self.entry.grid(row=row, column=i+1)
            self.entries.append(self.entry)

def board_strength():
    ''' Add project details and date and generate test labels'''
    lbl1 = Label(top_frame, text = 'Board Strength Properties', font = ('Arial Bold', 12))
    lbl1.pack(side = 'top')
    display_date = Label(top_frame, text = f'Date: {date}', font = ('Arial', 10))
    display_date.pack(anchor = 'w')
    sample_lable = Label(top_frame, text = 'Project Number:', font = ('Arial Bold', 10))
    sample_lable.pack(anchor = 'sw', side = 'left')
    sample_entry = Entry(top_frame, width = 15)
    sample_entry.pack(anchor = 'sw', side = 'left')
    
    for i in range(3):
        lbl = Label(btm_frame2, text = f'Test: {i+1}', font = ('Arial', 10))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=i+1)
    
    #First test
    ect_widgets = create_widgets(btm_frame2, test_name = 'ECT', units = 'kN/m', row = 1)
    ect_button = Button(btm_frame2,text='Add ECT', command = ect_widgets.add_entry)
    ect_button.grid(row=12,column= 1, pady = 20)

   # Next test
   # fct_widgets = create_widgets(btm_frame2, test_name = 'FCT', units = 'kPa', row = 1)
   # fct_button = Button(btm_frame2,text="FCT", command = fct_widgets.add_entry)
   # fct_button.grid(row=12,column= 2, pady = 20)

   # Next: Add FCT 

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

papermenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Paper", menu=papermenu)

boardmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Board", menu=boardmenu)
boardmenu.add_command(label="Strength Properties", command = board_strength)
boardmenu.add_command(label="Structural Properties", command= 'board_structure')
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: add_entry() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'window', 'test_name', 'units', and 'row'
```

Why does it still want these arguments if I've already passed them creating the instance ect_widget? And how do I increase the row number accordingly when new rows are added? The row numbers are going to be a headache.

Any help or input would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do post the full traceback

Comment: Here is the full traceback:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: add_entry() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'window', 'test_name', 'units', and 'row'

Comment: Could the error be at `ect_widgets.add_entry` where you are not passing in any arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet of the code you have offered isn't enough to actually run it so I'm sorry for minor errors, but I think I know what you are missing here.

You probably want the add_entry method to not have all those arguments required.  While it needs those things to do what it does; you can save that data in the instance of the class when you create it.

```
def __init__(self, window, test_name, units, row):
    self.window = window
    self.test_name = test_name
    self.units = units
    self.row = row
    self.add_entry()
  
def add_entry(self):
    self.entries = []

    lbl_of_test = Label(self.window,
        text = f'{self.test_name} ({self.units}):',
        font = ('Arial', 10))
    lbl_of_test.grid(row = self.row, column = 0)

    for i in range(3):
        self.entry = Entry(self.window, width=8)
        self.entry.grid(row=self.row, column=i+1)
        self.entries.append(self.entry)
```

Something like this is probably more appropriate.  We store attributes of an instance using that "self." syntax.   The "self.window = window" etc saves these things so you can use them whenever without passing them.  Then, in the add_entry method, it can use the saved values of those things by calling up the 'self.' version of them.

(Technically speaking, there is nothing magical about using the word 'self' before those variables; it works that way because 'self' is the first argument passed into non-static methods--including __init__--in a class.  Whatever is first refers to the instance of that class, ergo the typical name of 'self.'  If you ever needed to refer to the instance of a class within its own methods you would just use 'self.')

I hope that helps, let us know if you have more questions.

P.S.  I split up that really long line into multiple...generally, you don't want lines longer than 80 characters, and Python lets you cut lines freely between items inside of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you both for all your help! I solved my problem